# RabbitMQ Java API: I want to use basicGet() for RPC call. Can it be made to block? Can it be interrupted?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am fairly new to RabbitMQ, and starting on a project that is using RabbitMQ in a fairly old-fashioned "RPC" pattern. So I'm trying something like this on the "server" side:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri(uri);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare(queueName, false, false, false, null);
while (!shutdown) {
   GetResponse gr = channel.basicGet(queueName, true);
   ... build reply ...
   channel.basicPublish("", gr.getProps().getReplyTo(), replyProps, response);
}
```

My question is: can the thread waiting on basicGet() be interrupted?  If so, what happens (InterruptedException is not declared).  It realize this is not a great pattern, but I just want some way to cleanly shutdown a service.

UPDATE: one comment indicates that basicGet() does not block at all, and returns immediately if the queue is empty.  If that is the case, let me revise my question to be more precise: How do I wait for a message on a queue and retrieve it, with a timeout?

UPDATE2: After experimenting and asking questions on the rabbitmq mailing list, I conclude that this cannot be done directly. It is simply not The Way That You Do Things in RabbitMQ. Instead, you launch a consumer thread pool using Channel.basicConsume() and wait for your handler method to be called. It can be done **indirectly** by having your consumer post to a SynchronizedQueue or something similar and having your foreground thread(s) wait on that, but be warned that this defeats the automatic scaling offered by basicConsume() and also makes it harder to properly ACK all requests, and also creates additional message buffering that makes it difficult to honor QOS semantics set by the basicQos() call.

It should also be noted that, once you go down the basicConsume() route, the consumer **can** be interrupted.  This is done something like:

```
// This starts a background thread pool
String consumerTag = channel.basicConsume(consumer);
...
// Shutdown the consumer thread pool
channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);
```

UPDATE3: See last answer.  RabbitMQ comes with an RpcClient class that works splendidly.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the server itself could just post a "poison packet" to its own queue and check for it. Good solution? Seem OK for non-durable queues, but not so great for durable or shared queues.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I will ask the Java client maintainer to take a look at this question. PS - the RabbitMQ team monitors [the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have seen the "poison packet" technique used in some RabbitMQ examples for telling services that the end of a queue's input has been reached and they can now quit.  This could be useful if you launch a service running on a lifetime-limited queue. But not for interrupting a specific consumer in the same process.  That is best done via Channel.basicCancel().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basicGet` doesn't block, it returns immediately (well, just after a network  roundtrip) and returns null if there's no messages on the queue. So it's not necessary to interrupt the thread.

Comment: If that is the case, how does one wait for a message and retrieve it, with optional timeout?

Comment: There's no AMQP method to do that. One way to achieve this is to register a consumer with `basicConsume`, use a `BlockingQueue` in the consumer to enqueue incoming messages, and `poll` the `BlockingQueue` in a loop.

Comment: As was afraid you would say that :-)  
Alright, I'll mark this as answered even though I don't like the answer.

Comment: `basicGet doesn't block` I am not experiencing this at all. It appears to block indefinitely, or at least for the duration of `AMQPChannel._rpcTimeout` which defaults to `NO_RPC_TIMEOUT`. If a timeout it set, it appears to be wrapped in a `ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` and I'm still tracing what happens from there.

Comment: @drobert This is not the normal behavior, `basicGet` should take just a bit more than a network roundtrip, so I suspect there is something wrong with the connection or the channel. Please post your question with additional information (version of RabbitMQ and client, logs, steps to reproduce) to the [RabbitMQ user mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) so we can investigate further.

Comment: Hmm, I wrote a unit test to prove my situation and it did return immediately, but in a separate production use case I have evidence of this blocking for minutes. I will spend more time tracking down the circumstance that can cause this to block (likely something transactional with late-acking). I wanted to leave the note here because I didn't see any evidence or documentation supporting your claim and wanted the thought process in-context.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ java API comes with a very nice implementation of an RPCClient called, (unsurprisingly) RPCClient.  Use it! I made an [example in github](https://github.com/wheezil/rabbitmq-rpc-example)